# nginx location outside document root

Tags: nginx

I am new to nginx. Please help me to set up following configuration:
The root folder for site.com is `/var/www(root /var/www)`.
But when somebody opens http://site.com, I want to load contents from `/var/www/home`.
If somebody tries http://site.com/anything, I want to load contents from `/var/www/anything`.

I tried following

```
root /var/www;
location = / {
root /var/www/home
}
```

but it didn't work.

Also, I tried

```
location = / {
root /var/www/home
}

location / {
root /var/www
}
```

and again this didn't work,

Please help

Comment: doesn't work you mean you get a 404 or what ? and is the site php or rails or python , or just plain html ?

Comment: @Mohammad
its htmt. When try first option 
 `root /var/www;
location = / {
root /var/www/home
}`
it always match /var/www
In second also location / matching always. I think site.com will match location = /   but it will not

Comment: did you define the index in the server scope ? `index index.html;`

Comment: @Mohammad
yes it is there in server scope

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
location ~ ^/$ {
    root /var/www/home;
}
location ~ ^(?!/$) {
    root /var/www;
}
```

or this:

```
location / {
    root /var/www;
    rewrite ^/$ /home/ break;
}
```

Comment: Tried the first option  but it always taking first location. That is both site.com and site.com/anything match 
    
`location ~ ^/$ {
    root /var/www/home;}`

The second option works and it loads index.html file from /var/www/home/ but it was not able load css,js and img folder located at /var/wwww/home. It is trying read those folders from /var/www. I modified that rewrite by removing end slash that is `rewrite ^/$ /home break; It works perfectly but url is redirecting to site.com/home`. Can we do this without url change or without rewrite

Comment: Change that rewrite slightly: `rewrite ^/$ /home/index.html break;`.

Comment: @user2584292 you must create a rule for its static too.